# Как можно добавить layout.xml в main_activity.xml в java коде?

Tags: java, android, layout

Здравствуйте уважаемые программисты.Пытаюсь сделать так чтобы добавлять подготовленные `layout.xml` файлы с разметкой добавить в главное окно.Как фрагменты. Не в `onCreate`, а допустим в каком нибудь `actionlistener(View view){}`.Внутрь какого нибудь `LinearLayout`

Можно ли делать? Если можно то как? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приблизительно так:

```
//берем контейнер внутрь которого собираемся впихнуть
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
//наш лейаут
View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child, null);
//добавляем в контейнер
container.addView(child);
```

Comment: Пасиба дядя Бармалей!!!!